# can super saiyan god (red) kaioken be made just like super saiyan god super saiyan kaioken?

Tags: anime, dragon-ball-z

In the last manga Goku is able to transform in super saiyan god red by his own, without the other 5 saiyans surrounding him ritual. My question is, in this transformation, can he use the kaioken on top of it, just as he used with the super saiyan god super saiyan transformation (super saiyan blue)?

Comment: I thought anime and manga were off-topic here? And that questions about them should be asked on http://anime.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I dont know, I just saw an "anime" tag here, so I asked

Comment: @BCdotWEB Questions about sci-fi/fantasy anime are on-topic both here and at Anime and Manga. Anime and manga without sci-fi/fantasy elements, or general questions about anime and manga, are off-topic here but on-topic at A&M. See http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/643/28578, and also http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2900/28578.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, no one knows yet, but the answer is most likely yes.
The reason it would be no is that God-mode is literally using a different type of ki and at least in some way uses different principles which may preclude the use of Kaioken and how it works.

Because it is not explicit in the manga nor anime (though I haven't been keeping up, but I'm pretty sure they're still in the movie remake episodes) and there is no evidence to weigh down an answer on either side there is no concrete answer here.